# Not finding my HBase table columns in my Phoenix table

Tags: hbase, apache-phoenix

1. Created my HBase table:

> hbase(main):091:0> create 't20', {NAME => 'f2', VERSIONS => 5}

2. put data:

> hbase(main):092:0> put 't20' , '1112', 'f2:name', 'aash2'

3. scan:

> > scan 't20' ROW                                                COLUMN+CELL
> >     1112                                              column=f2:name,
> >     timestamp=1452552357302, value=aash2

4. create view in Phoenix to map to it:

> 0: jdbc:phoenix:localhost> CREATE VIEW "t20" ( pk VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY,
>   "f2".name VARCHAR );

4. "scan' it:

   > jdbc:phoenix:localhost> select * from "t20"
   >
   > ;
   >   +---------------------------------------+ |
   >                   PK                               |                   NAME
   >   |
   >   +--+------------------------------------+ | 1112                                     | null
   >   |

why is it not showing my value? why is that 'null' ?

5. Desc gives also a different column name that i would expect:

   > ```
   >  0: jdbc:phoenix:localhost> !describe "t20";
   > ```
   >
   > |                TABLE_CAT                 |               TABLE_SCHEM                |                TABLE_NAME                |               COLUMN_NAME                |                DAT |

> | null                                     | null                      | t20                                      | PK                        | 12
>
> null                                     |
>   null                                     | t20                         | NAME                                     | 12                 |

Phoenix version: 4.2.2

any idea?

thanks,

Matt

Comment: Check answer to this question : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34119543/column-family-with-apache-phoenix)

Comment: yes that solved it ! Needed to do "CREATE VIEW "t20" ( pk VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY, "f2"."name" VARCHAR );" -> note the " around name.